# Set multiple UIButton's font size to be equal when using fit to width

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uibutton

I have 2 UIButtons in a view controller that have a certain fixed width. Because the app needs to support multiple languages, I need to be able to adjust their font size so the text will always fit in that fixed width.

However, when I use: `button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`, one button's font size will be larger than the other.

Thus, I need both font sizes to be at their minimum font size, based on the fit to width.

I found this question but was unable to convert it to Swift: [Adjust the font size to fit for several UIButton's so that they all have the same font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990204/adjust-the-font-size-to-fit-for-several-uibuttons-so-that-they-all-have-the-sam)

I tried:

```
func customizeFontSize() {
        button1.setTitle("text 1", for: .normal)
        button2.setTitle("text 2", for: .normal)
        let minFont1: Float = self.idealFontSize(for: button1)
        let minFont2: Float = self.idealFontSize(for: button2)
        let fontSize: Float = min(minFont1, minFont2)
        let tailoredFont = button1.titleLabel!.font.withSize(CGFloat(fontSize))
        self.button1.titleLabel!.font = tailoredFont
        self.button2.titleLabel!.font = tailoredFont
    }

    func idealFontSize(for button: UIButton) -> Float {
        let label = button.titleLabel!
        let temp: Float = 10.0
        let width: Float = Float(button.bounds.size.width) - temp
        assert(button.bounds.size.width >= label.bounds.size.width)
        let actualFontSize: CGFloat

        //unavailable in swift
        label.text!.size(with: label.font, minFontSize: label.minimumFontSize, actualFontSize: actualFontSize, forWidth: width, lineBreakMode: label.lineBreakMode)
        debug("idealFontSizeForButton %f", actualFontSize)

        return Float(actualFontSize)
    }
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. Figured out that much better approach is to put buttons in `UIStackView` and set its distribution mode to proportional. That way if there's not enough space to fit full-size content, each element will be sized down proportionally.

Example code:

```
let stackview = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [leftButton, rightButton])
stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackview.spacing = 16
stackview.axis = .horizontal
stackview.distribution = .fillProportionally
stackview.alignment = .center
addSubview(stackview)
stackview.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 
UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 80).isActive = true
```

The code above misses 2 things:

1. Layout constraints that would set stackview's position on x and y axis
2. Proper width anchor - that should be set on layoutSubviews or be driven by some other autolayout constraint

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to compare both font sizes and use the smaller one. Untested example:

In `viewDidLoad`

```
//let button1 = UIButton()
//var button2 = UIButton()

button1.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button2.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

In viewDidAppear:

```
let size1: CGFloat = (button1.titleLabel?.font.pointSize)!
let size2: CGFloat = (button2.titleLabel?.font.pointSize)!

if size1.isLess(than: size2) {
    button2.titleLabel?.font = button1.titleLabel?.font
} else if size2.isLess(than: size1) {
    button1.titleLabel?.font = button2.titleLabel?.font
}
```

Comment: This seems like a simplified version of my code above, but I still cannot get it to work. The font sizes are not equal :/

Comment: By printing the font.pointsize of both buttons after the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth method, I can see that their font size is still equal. The adjustsFontSizeToWidth method does not seem to change the font size itself, but rather scale it in some way?

Comment: I assume it's not drawn yet. Updated answer.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything, font.pointsize remains unchanged in both cases :/

Comment: For those who are seeing unchanged font.pointsize this wander worked for me!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607209/10419856